# MongoDb is connected but cannot store title and body

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, body-parser

I am a beginner and starting to learn MongoDB, NodeJS and Express by creating a simple blog project. I facing a problem as my data cannot be stored in my MongoDB event though my MongoDB connects properly. There may be a mistake in my coding in index.js. I try to fix it, but it does not store the information that I submit in the blog. Please help me. Thank you.

This is my code in index.js. You can see my full file in this link if you want to test it. [enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1MF5eTrsN2Ry5nIaf-ay-JJJvc9H4gH9G?usp=sharing)

This is my index.js

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/my_database',{useNewUrlParser: true})

const app = new express()
const ejs = require('ejs')

const BlogPost = require('./models/BlogPost')

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.use(express.static('public'))

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

const { error } = require('console')

app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('App listening on port 4000')
});

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('index')
})

app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
    res.render('about');
});

app.get('/contact', (req, res) => {
    res.render('contact');
});

app.get('/post',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('post')
 })

 app.get('/posts/new',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('create')
})

app.post('/posts/store',(req,res)=>{
    BlogPost.create(req.body,(error,blogpost)=>{
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});
```

This what it show in my MongoDB compass

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYWrA.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the database connection URL is not correct .

You can use following code,

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 

mongoose.connect(db_url,{ useNewUrlParser: true }, function (err) { 
if (err) throw err; console.log('Successfully connected'); });
```

Comment: Reference:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/

Comment: I try to change the connection like you suggested but my app become error..it show **[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...**

Comment: If you are getting error so its mean there is some problem 
try to read the error or paste the whole error here so i can help you

Comment: Hi..it is error if the database can connect as when I click submit in my blog, it show that data store in mongodb but there is no value in the content. I edit the post to show you the image of my database..btw i use localhost

Answer (score 0):

```
app.post('/posts/store',async (req,res)=>{
    let blog = await BlogPost.create(req.body);
    res.render('index',blog);
});
```

you can access the blog data inside the index file by blog variable

Comment: Hi..I try as you suggest but it still not save my submit data..it show that data in but there is no content..
**_id: 6359d9de013c0014306f7ae2
__v: 0**

There is no title or body that been save

Comment: console the req.body if the value is coming or not also check property is same as the blogPost schema .

Comment: Hi.. do you mean do it like this?.. 

`app.post('/posts/store',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.body.title)
    console.log(req.body.body)
    res.redirect('/')
})`

I done this but my terminal show crash **[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...**

This my code in BlogPost.js
`const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const BlogPostSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    body: String
});

const BlogPost = mongoose.model('BlogPost',BlogPostSchema);

module.exports = BlogPost`

Comment: i already got the answer..The problem is in my create.ejs.. I need to change `enctype="multipart/form-data">`  to `enctype="multipart/x-www-form-urlencoded">`  Thank you so much for helping me.